# Is there an optimal way to find unique elements within N sets with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, intersect

I'm currently working on an example where I have 45 data frames with around 60,000 strings entries. I would like to know which of the strings are unique when compared to all of the other data frames (or sets) that I have, `entry_df['strings']` in the example.

I tried using the library supervenn (https://github.com/gecko984/supervenn) to plot both unique and shared elements within the different sets, but my data is too big to be plotted with this library.

Is there an optimal way to finding these unique elements? I'd like to compare at least 9 groups at once, so that `A.intersect B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I = ∅`. I thought of iteratively looping over each one of the sets and removing common elements, but I didn't find a way to optimize the memory usage. The code that I've used for plotting the supervenn graph was:

```
entry_files = glob('../*/dataframe.csv')

allentries = []
labels = []

for f in entry_files:
    entry_df = pd.read_csv(f)
    string_set = set(entry_df['strings'].unique().tolist())
    allentries.append(string_set)
    labels.append(f'{entry_df.type.unique()}')

import supervenn

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
supervenn.supervenn(allentries, labels, widths_minmax_ratio=0.45)
```

Comment: I think the most optimal way would be to sort all arrays then loop only once and check each array for each index. If dup, do something like pop.

Comment: or, if you don't care about keeping the arrays separate, you can combine into 1 array, sort, then remove dups in single loop fairly easily. There are many ways to do this but it kind of depends on the data and what you want to achieve. Ideally, one loop at most though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the elements that are placed only once in all the sets, you can use operation ^ for the sets.

set1 ^ set2

returns a set of all elements in either set1 or set2, but not both.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know about this operator

Comment: Don't forget to mark the response as solving if this solution will help you.

Comment: The following should produce the same result at the above operator for 2 sets: `set1.symmetric_difference(set2)`